# Windows unforced (not forced, graceful) restart (reboot)

Tags: windows, scheduled-task, shutdown

I wish to restart Windows 7 x64 by schedule, but the shutdown process needs not to be forced, but applications allowed to end normally. I have used scheduled task and system utility `shutdown.exe` with arguments `/r /t 60 /d p:8:0` and there are no `/f` argument, isn't it? But the Shutdown utility have forced the restart. Is there inappropriate arguments used? Why the utility forces restart? And how to schedule task that restarts Windows normally?

Comment: That's because of /t timeout not equals 0, see `shutdown /?`

Comment: Oh, you're completely right! How could I not notice this? Post it as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Feel free to add it yourself :) My answer is not complete - I didn't offer you a way to schedule restart. So I hope someone will add something useful, eg. `at` command syntax... Good luck!

Comment: @kay27 Thanks. I have noted in my question, that _I have used scheduled task_, so I can use scheduling already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is described in the Shutdown utility help: everyone in this case should read it (the help) attentively enough, about all arguments, but not only about those, which are need to be used.

---

The help states, that if `/t` subargument >0, then `/f` applies automatically (and can't be disabled, if I understood properly).

Comment: Is `/f` really can't be disabled in case of `/t` subargument >0?